# Creating a configuration file for Prometheus

Tags: ansible

Inventory file (inventories/test/environments/tmp6.yml):

```yaml
test:
  children:
    environments:
      children:
        tmp6:

tmp6:
  vars:
    ansible_user: superuser
    ansible_password: superuser
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  children:
    infra:
      hosts:
        host_5:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.72
        host_6:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.83
    tools:
      hosts:
        host_7:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.239
        host_8:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.46
```

General `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: environments
  roles:
    - role: host-configuration
    - role: host-users
    - role: node-exporter
  post_tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          - target: 
              - {{ ansible_host }}:9100
            labels:
              environment_name: {{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '') }}
              environment_type: {{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}
        dest: "./{{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

After successfully installing the node_exporter on the nodes, need to create a common configuration file for the environment:

```yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.72:9100
    - 192.168.1.83:9100
    - 192.168.1.239:9100
    - 192.168.1.46:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp6
    environment_type: test
```

The main problem in formation the list of targets.

If create such a template:

```yaml
- target: 
    - {{ ansible_host }}:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: {{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '') }}
    environment_type: {{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}
```

value of the variable `ansible_host` always changes. **Therefore it is not a solution.**

How to create a dynamic host list in a playbook?

P.S.: Playbook can be applied to multiple environments:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventories/test -l tmp1,tmp3,tmp6
```

---

General task:

1. install the node_exporter on the nodes of group "environments"
2. create a common configuration files on the localhost
3. copy the configuration files to the host "prometheus"

Comment: "value of the variable ansible_host always changes" It only changes when you run the playbook on different hosts...which wouldn't make any sense for this sort of template. Can you update the question to show us your template task?

Comment: This is the problem, template is not correct. Another solution is needed. But I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you don't show us your existing playbook we'll have a hard time suggesting how to fix it.

Comment: Updated the playbook.yml. **But template is not correct**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with intermediate temporary files.

1. Creating temporary files:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "./.configs_prometheus/{{
           inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}_--_{{
           ansible_host }}_--_{{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '') }}"
    state: touch
```

2. Search for temporary files

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "./.configs_prometheus/"
    file_type: file
    recurse: yes
  register: environment_temp_files_list
```

3. Generating data lists:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    environment_data: "{{ environment_temp_files_list.files | map(attribute='path') | map('ansible.builtin.basename') |
                          map('ansible.builtin.split','_--_') | map('ansible.builtin.zip', ['type', 'host', 'name']) |
                          map('map', 'reverse') | map('community.general.dict') | groupby('name') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: environments_list="{{ environment_data | map('first') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: hosts_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='host') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: types_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='type') | map('ansible.builtin.unique') }}"
```

4. Template generation:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: |
      - targets:
        {%  for result in item.1.0 %}
        - {{ result }}:9100
        {% endfor %}
      labels:
          environment_name: {{ item.0 }}
          environment_type: {{ item.1.1.0 }}
    dest: "./.configs_prometheus/{{ item.1.1.0 }}_--_{{ item.0 }}.yml"
  loop: "{{ environments_list | zip( hosts_list | zip(types_list) ) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0 }}"
```

---

Final playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Creating a directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "./.configs_prometheus"
        state: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop:
        - absent
        - directory

- hosts: environments
  roles:
    - role: host-configuration
    - role: host-users
    - role: node-exporter
  post_tasks:
    - name: Creating temporary files
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "./.configs_prometheus/{{
               inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}_--_{{
               ansible_host }}_--_{{ inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '') }}"
        state: touch
      delegate_to: localhost

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Search for temporary files
      ansible.builtin.find:
        paths: "./.configs_prometheus/"
        file_type: file
        recurse: yes
      register: environment_temp_files_list

    - name: Generating data lists
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        environment_data: "{{ environment_temp_files_list.files | map(attribute='path') | map('ansible.builtin.basename') |
                              map('ansible.builtin.split','_--_') | map('ansible.builtin.zip', ['type', 'host', 'name']) |
                              map('map', 'reverse') | map('community.general.dict') | groupby('name') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: environments_list="{{ environment_data | map('first') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: hosts_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='host') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: types_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='type') | map('ansible.builtin.unique') }}"

    - name: Template generation
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          - targets:
            {%  for result in item.1.0 %}
            - {{ result }}:9100
            {% endfor %}
          labels:
              environment_name: {{ item.0 }}
              environment_type: {{ item.1.1.0 }}
        dest: "./.configs_prometheus/{{ item.1.1.0 }}_--_{{ item.0 }}.yml"
      loop: "{{ environments_list | zip( hosts_list | zip(types_list) ) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0 }}"

    - name: Deleting temporary files
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ environment_temp_files_list.files | map(attribute='path') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.split('/').1 }}"
```

---

---

---

**UPDATE**

The problem can be solved without intermediate temporary files.

1. Creating environment dataset:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    environment_dataset: |
      {% for play_host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
        - {{ hostvars[play_host].inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}_--_{{
             hostvars[play_host].ansible_host }}_--_{{
             hostvars[play_host].inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '')
          }}
      {% endfor %}
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  delegate_facts: true
  loop: "{{ groups['prometheus'] | default(['localhost']) }}"
```

2. Generating data lists:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    environment_data: "{{ environment_dataset | from_yaml |
                          map('ansible.builtin.split','_--_') | map('ansible.builtin.zip', ['type', 'host', 'name']) |
                          map('map', 'reverse') | map('community.general.dict') | groupby('name') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: environments_list="{{ environment_data | map('first') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: hosts_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='host') }}"

- ansible.builtin.set_fact: types_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='type') | map('ansible.builtin.unique') }}"
```

3. Template generation:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.copy:
    content: |
      - targets:
        {%  for result in item.1.0 %}
        - {{ result }}:9100
        {% endfor %}
      labels:
          environment_name: {{ item.0 }}
          environment_type: {{ item.1.1.0 }}
    dest: "/etc/prometheus/file_sd_configs/{{ item.1.1.0 }}_--_{{ item.0 }}.yml"
  loop: "{{ environments_list | zip( hosts_list | zip(types_list) ) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0 }}"
```

---

Final playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: environments
  roles:
    - role: host-configuration
    - role: host-users
    - role: node-exporter
  post_tasks:
    - name: Creating temporary files
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        environment_dataset: |
          {% for play_host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
            - {{ hostvars[play_host].inventory_file | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.dirname | ansible.builtin.basename }}_--_{{
                 hostvars[play_host].ansible_host }}_--_{{
                 hostvars[play_host].inventory_file | ansible.builtin.basename | ansible.builtin.regex_replace('.yml$', '')
              }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: true
      loop: "{{ groups['prometheus'] | default(['localhost']) }}"

- hosts: prometheus
  tasks:
    - name: Generating data lists
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        environment_data: "{{ environment_dataset | from_yaml |
                              map('ansible.builtin.split','_--_') | map('ansible.builtin.zip', ['type', 'host', 'name']) |
                              map('map', 'reverse') | map('community.general.dict') | groupby('name') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: environments_list="{{ environment_data | map('first') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: hosts_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='host') }}"
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact: types_list="{{ environment_data | map('last') | map('map', attribute='type') | map('ansible.builtin.unique') }}"

    - name: Template generation
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          - targets:
            {%  for result in item.1.0 %}
            - {{ result }}:9100
            {% endfor %}
          labels:
              environment_name: {{ item.0 }}
              environment_type: {{ item.1.1.0 }}
        dest: "/etc/prometheus/file_sd_configs/{{ item.1.1.0 }}_--_{{ item.0 }}.yml"
      become: yes
      loop: "{{ environments_list | zip( hosts_list | zip(types_list) ) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0 }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> If multiple environments are used, multiple files must be created

Ansible doesn't know anything about your "environments". If you want to use that information in your playbooks, you'll need to add it to your inventory. For example, we can add `environment_type` and `environment_name` variables like this:

```yaml
test:
  vars:
    environment_type: test
  children:
    environments:
      children:
        tmp5:
        tmp6:

tmp5:
  vars:
    environment_name: tmp5
  children:
    tmp5_infra:
      hosts:
        host_1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
        host_2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
    tmp5_tools:
      hosts:
        host_3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.3
        host_4:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.4

tmp6:
  vars:
    environment_name: tmp6
  children:
    tmp6_infra:
      hosts:
        host_5:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.5
        host_6:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.6
    tmp6_tools:
      hosts:
        host_7:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.7
        host_8:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.8
```

Given the above inventory file, we can write a playbook like this:

```yaml
- hosts: environments
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    # This task groups hosts by environment_name
    - delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      set_fact:
        env_to_host: >
          {{ env_to_host|combine({
            hostvars[item].environment_name: env_to_host.get(hostvars[item].environment_name, []) + [item]
          })}}
      vars:
        env_to_host: {}

    - delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      loop: "{{ env_to_host.keys() }}"
      copy:
        content: |
          - target: 
          {% for host in env_to_host[item] %}
              - {{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}:9100
          {% endfor %}
            labels:
              environment_name: {{ item }}
              environment_type: {{ hostvars[env_to_host[item]|first].environment_type }}
        dest: "./config-{{item}}.yaml"
```

If we run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

We get:

```
$ ls config*
config-tmp5.yaml  config-tmp6.yaml
$ cat config-tmp5.yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.1:9100
    - 192.168.1.2:9100
    - 192.168.1.3:9100
    - 192.168.1.4:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp5
    environment_type: test
$ cat config-tmp6.yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.5:9100
    - 192.168.1.6:9100
    - 192.168.1.7:9100
    - 192.168.1.8:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp6
    environment_type: test
```

If we limit by environment, like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -l tmp5
```

We get:

```
$ ls config*
config-tmp5.yaml
$ cat config-tmp5.yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.1:9100
    - 192.168.1.2:9100
    - 192.168.1.3:9100
    - 192.168.1.4:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp5
    environment_type: test
```

And finally, if we limit to individual hosts, like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -l host_1,host_5
```

We get:

```
$ ls config*
config-tmp5.yaml  config-tmp6.yaml
$ cat config-tmp5.yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.1:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp5
    environment_type: test
$ cat config-tmp6.yaml
- target:
    - 192.168.1.5:9100
  labels:
    environment_name: tmp6
    environment_type: test
```

Comment: 1. Updated the task
2. Your solution is not suitable if you run a playbook on multiple environments (`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventories/test -l tmp1,tmp3,tmp6`). If multiple environments are used, multiple files must be created (tmp1.yml, tmp3.yml, tmp6.yml)